# Detecting the position of the 1 bit value in the less significative position VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a 32-bit word. I need to create a new 32-bit word containing just the first bit with value 1 in the less significative position using VHDL.

Example:

INPUT : 01000010 01001011 00000000 00100010
OUTPUT: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010

Comment: An if then elsif... if statement testing input bits in priority order Only one test condition evaluates true. The equivalent conditional signal assignment.  A for loop with an exit inside and enclosed if statement testing the loop constant input bit.  The idea is only the highest priority bit is set and the rest are reset.

Comment: You haven't specified whether this is for behavioral modeling or synthesis.

Comment: @user1155120 : behavioral code can be synthesised. The question would be whether he wants it in behavioral or in structural modelling.

Comment: All VHDL models are behavioral  - IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design." Structure is superimposed by internal or external block statements. There are however VHDL design specifications that can't be synthesized.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is traverse the input from the highest priority end to the lowest priority end in order and when encountering a '1' generate a value on the output with that corresponding position a '1' and the remaining positions '0'. After finding the first such match you quit.

Five ways come to mind. Using an if statement, a conditional signal assignment (or a conditional variable assignment in -2008), a loop statement with an exit, a case statement and a selected signal assignment (or a selected variable assignment in -2008).

Some of these are dependent on VHDL standard revision level and support for synthesis isn't guaranteed.

The simplest to express is the for loop shown in a process:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity priority_mapper is
    port (
        input:  in  std_logic_vector (0 to 31);
        output: out std_logic_vector (0 to 31)
    );
end entity;

architecture foe of priority_mapper is

begin
MAPIT:
    process (input)
    begin
        output <= (others => '0');
        for i in input'reverse_range loop 
            if input(i) = '1' then
                output(i) <= '1';
                exit;     
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

For your sample stimulus:

```
input <= B"01000010_01001011_00000000_00100010";
```

It produces the output:

> priority_mapper.vhdl:136:13:@10ns:(report note): output = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010

It was a tad more complex to put the spaces in the testbench output:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity priority_mapper_tb is
end entity;

architecture tb of priority_mapper_tb is
    signal input:  std_logic_vector (0 to 31) := (others => '0');
    signal output: std_logic_vector (0 to 31) := (others => '0');
begin
DUT:
    entity work.priority_mapper (foe)
        port map (input, output);
STIMULUS:
    input <= B"01000010_01001011_00000000_00100010" after 10 ns;
RESPONSE:
    process (output)
        variable  output_string: string (1 to 35);
        variable j: integer range output_string'range;
    begin
        if now > 0 ns then
            j := 1;
            for i in output'range loop
                if i = 8 or i = 16 or i = 24 then
                    output_string(j) := ' ';
                    j :=  j + 1;
                end if;
                output_string(j) :=         
                            character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(output(i)));
                if j < output_string'right then
                    j := j + 1;
                end if;
            end loop;
            report "output = " & output_string;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The code to accept spaces in a string input would be about as complex, converting the characters representing values to a std_logic array value. You hadn't show type declaration so it seemed a bit of work. The output spaces were whimsy.